# Права доступа Android (GPS) API 19

Tags: java, android, gps, permissions

Недавно изучаю Android.

API 19. Пытаюсь получить координаты местоположения. Сделал по примеру 1 сайта, но возник вопрос с правами доступа. В примере данный код рабочий.

Начальный код

AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

MainActivity

```
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            showLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            checkEnabled();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            checkEnabled();
            showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                tvStatusGPS.setText("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));
            } else if (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                tvStatusNet.setText("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));
            }
        }
    };
```

Не нравится ему строчка, я так понял, что нет прав доступа.

```
 showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
```

Предлагает исправить на

```
@Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            checkEnabled();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
        }
```

А потом ругается на this

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.location.LocationListener',
>   required: 'android.content.Context'

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаете экземпляр анонимного класса, реализующего интерфейс `LocationListener`. В блоке кода:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    ...
};
```

`this` – это ссылка на экземпляр этого анонимного класса.

Метод `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(...)` первым параметром требует `Context`, а Вы, получается, передаете `LocationListener`.

Замените `this` либо на `YourActivityName.class`, либо на `getActivity()`, либо на что-то, что наследуется от класса `Context`.

Comment: Создал getter Activity и все заработало. Спасибо большое.